# How to determine/calculate distance of bluetooth device in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

I've been struggling lately with **flutter** and its **flutterblue** module to accomplish reading and writing data to a bluetooth device, but I happens no chance to achieve what I need.

Below is my code to scan for devices and their data:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4), scanMode: ScanMode.lowPower);

    return Scaffold(

           body:StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults.asBroadcastStream(),
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) {

                      List <ScanResult> results = snapshot.data;

                      return ListView.separated(
                       itemBuilder: (context, index){
                         var device = results[index].device;
                         var name = device.name.length > 0? device.name:"Unknown";
                         
                         return ListTile(
                             title: Text(name),
                             subtitle: Text(device.id.toString()),
                              trailing: RaisedButton(
                                child: Text("connect"),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if( results[index].advertisementData.connectable == true) {
                                    device.connect();
                                    device.state.listen((event) async {
                                        print("The device state is now ${event}");
                                    });
                                  }
                              else{
                                   showDialog(context: context, builder: (d){
                                     return AlertDialog(content: Text("The device is not connectable"));
                                    });
                                  }
                                  
                                },
                              ),
                         );
                       },
                     separatorBuilder: (context, index){
                       return Divider();
                     },
                     itemCount: results.length
                   );
                 },
                  ),
      

    );
}
```

Unfortunately, however much I tried, the scan results' devices show no any useful data than empty values, **device id** and **manufacturer data**, what I want is to grab the device data, including ***name*** and from the grabbed data, calculate the distance to the scanned device.
I wonder if this can be achieved in Flutter anyway.

Your help will be much much much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am calling it, just below **build** method... and above the **Scaffold** widget.